# First python screen scraping and smtp script won't evaluate properly

Tags: python, int, urllib2, smtplib

Here's my script with the personal bits scrubbed.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
resp3 = opener.open('https://www.mynexia.com/login')
resp4 = resp3.read().split('input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"')
resp5 = resp4[1].split('\" /></div>')
login = 'website username'
password = 'website pass'
authenticity_token = resp5
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : login, 'password' : password,'authenticity_token' : authenticity_token})
opener.open('https://www.mynexia.com/session', login_data)
resp = opener.open('https://www.mynexia.com/houses/ourstaticaccountpage/climate')
resp1 = resp.read().split('<div class=\"temperature\"><span>')
resp2 = resp1[1].split('</span></div>')

int(resp2[0])


if resp2[0] > 75:

    import smtplib
    import string
    SUBJECT = "Temperature is rising!"
    TO = "helpdesk@whoever.blah"
    FROM = "me@gmail.com"
    text = "Temperature is " + resp2[0]
    BODY = string.join((
        "From: %s" % FROM,
        "To: %s" % TO,
        "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT,
        "",
        text
        ), "\r\n")
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("me@gmail.com", "gmailpass")
    server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)

elif resp2[0] <= 75:

    import smtplib
    import string
    SUBJECT = "Temperature is ok"
    TO = "helpdesk@whereever.blah"
    FROM = "me@gmail.com"
    text = "Temperature is " + resp2[0]
    BODY = string.join((
        "From: %s" % FROM,
        "To: %s" % TO,
        "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT,
        "",
        text
        ), "\r\n")
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("me@gmail.com", "gmailpass")
    server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
```

It works fine, except it always evaluates `resp2[0]` as `> 75` no matter what its value is. The point of this script is to alert me when a room that some sensitive machines are running in gets warmer than 75 degrees. The website I'm scraping from only allows you to send alerts if it gets over 90. By then I'm at risk of machines going down, so I wanted to alert myself earlier. I'm going to run it with a cronjob every 15 minutes, and once I get the if-else statement working right, I'm just going to have <= dump to a log file instead of sending out an "Everything is a-ok alert." Any suggestions on why I fail at basic math? Is there a problem with my `int(resp2[0])`? Is it not base 10 by default?

Comment: I would suggest using an X/HTML parser library instead of trying to parse the HTML from scratch. No need to reinvent the wheel. http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: That part is already done. It works fine [until they change the source on either page :)], and it was fun to do. My problem is the if-elif section under int(resp2[0]) always evaluates resp2[0] as being greater than 75 even when it isn't. This will lead to unnecessary emails every 15 minutes and having to read every instance to see if the temp is actually running hot or not.

Comment: it seems to me that if resp2 is always greater than 75 and your sure the value you are trying to get is not > 75 then you are getting the wrong value.  An HTML parsing library such as htmlparser or beautiful soup would be invaluable.

Comment: No, resp2 comes out correctly. I think it's staying a string instead of an integer so it isn't being evaluated properly. The text of the email that gets sent prints resp2[0], and it's always correct. I log into the page to check it after I receive the alert.

Comment: It just needed int(resp2[0]) to be stored as an integer in a string.
I changed 

     int(resp2[0])

to 

     temp = int(resp2[0])

and the resp2[0]s in the if and elifs to temp, and it works perfectly now. It was such a dumb mistake it was hard to google. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resp2` is a list of *strings*. A string is greater than an integer. You need to call `int` on it before comparison.

Actually, I see that you are calling `int` - but you're not doing anything with the result. Doing `int(resp2[0])` doesn't convert the contents of `resp2[0]` to an integer. It simply *returns* the converted value. If you don't assign it to anything, it just gets thrown away. You need to assign it to a new variable, and then use that variable in your `if` statements.

Comment: I figured it was that. Um, sorry for the noob question, but I couldn't figure out exactly how to google it. How do I make it into a variable I can evaluate in the if statement lower? I tried 
    int(resp2[0]) = temp 
and I got 
    SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
How do I save it as a variable to use elsewhere?

Comment: Awesome. Changed it to 
temp = int(resp2[0]) and the if elifs to temp and it works great.
Winner winner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the value of resp2[0] to see what values you are getting?  A simple

```
print resp2[0]
```

while debugging...

Comment: Yes, if you notice:
    text = "Temperature is " + resp2[0]
prints the temp in the body of the email that's sent. It is always correct (I check it against the website every time I run it). I think it's staying a string though and not being turned into an integer by the 
    int(resp2[0])
because I'm stupid and don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: temp = int(resp2[0]) and using temp in the if and elif sorted it out. Thanks!